# How can I perform database operations on the server. - with Laravel 6.0?

Tags: laravel, cpanel, laravel-6

Normally everything works fine on localhost. When I throw the project to the server, only the homepage works.

When I add manually to this section from the database, I can pull the data.

Web site here: http://elsetea.com/public (running)
but when I send a message from the contact section, my routes don't work (http://elsetea.com/public/#messages). What can I do in this situation.

Contact routing is as follows.

```
Route::namespace('Frontend')->group(function () {
    Route::post('contact', 'ContactPageController@store')->name('contact-page.store');
});
```

Comment: Is `public` referring to the `public` folder in your app or is it part of your routes file?

Comment: part of the routes file(https://prntscr.com/r6kcin)

Comment: You've said it's part of one of your route files but you shown a screenshot or your directory structure?

Comment: So this is the project directory I put on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I have taken the action as below and sending the message has been successful. But there was no informative message that should come out later.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;


class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Indicates whether the XSRF-TOKEN cookie should be set on the response.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $addHttpCookie = true;

    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        //
        '/contact'
    ];


}
```